# How to stop TCPServer OnExecute event from infinite execution after AContext.Connection.Disconnect?

Tags: delphi, indy, tcpserver

I have this `TCPServerExecute` event that I want to stop from executing after I manually disconnect the connection with the client :

```
procedure TMainForm.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  TCPClient : TIdTCPClient;
begin
try
  TCPClient := nil;
  try
    TCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
    if aConditionIsMet then begin 
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('Disconnected from server.');
      AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
      Exit;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(TCPClient);
  end;
except on e : Exception do
  begin
    MainForm.Log('error in Execute=' + e.Message);
  end;
end;
end;
```

and at client side everything's fine but on server-side I loop through TCPServerExecute infinitely. What am I doing wrong and how can I stop `TCPServerExecute` from executing after I type `AContext.Connection.Disconnect` ?

Comment: why does the code create a TIdTCPClient and then not use it at all? (the OnExecute event handler is executed in a loop, so this will cause high load)

Comment: @mjn It's not used because I haven't passed the entire code of the procedure - only a small part from it where the problem still occurs.

Comment: Instead of using a global boolean flag to disconnect the clients, you can set `TCPServer.Active := False` and the server will disconnect all connected clients

Comment: @mjn And if I want to disconnect only the current client isn't `AContext.Connection.Disconnect` the way to do that ?

Comment: Yes, but `aConditionIsMet` somehow needs to know if the current AContext belongs to the connection which should be disconnected. So it would be a function like `ConditionIsMet(AContext: TIdContext)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop continues because Indy exceptions are not handled correctly.

Either remove the exception handler, or re-raise the exception after logging:

```
except 
  on e : Exception do
  begin
    MainForm.Log('error in Execute=' + e.Message);
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

p.s. accessing the MainForm from the server thread is not thread-safe. There are many solutions to do improve this code (TThread.Queue is one of them).

Comment: Although you are right about eating all exceptions, something tells me this will be more difficult than a simple re-raise, because I think that you shouldn't let a client's exception bubble to the server.

Comment: @mjn - Removing the exception handler worked but I don't know what you mean by "re-raise the exception after logging" ?

Comment: @TLama Indy TIdTCPServer is designed to use exceptions this way: let them bubble, the server will take care of them. And some Indy specific exception types will cause a client disconnect.

Comment: @mjn - Thanks a lot - both of your solutions worked nicely :)

Comment: @mjn, that depends on application. What if it's not wanted to *kill the server connection* when the inner client fails ? What if you would like to tell to the server's client kindly that the inner client failed ?

Comment: @TLama now I understand you are talking about the TCPClient created dynamically in the OnExecute event handler - yes this is a different part of the storey, which needs its own exception handling and business logic to decide wether to bubble or not